# Movie Jail, expression intraduisible ?

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

Extrait d'un article du journal :

> [Paul Feig] revient de loin. Du « *Movie Jail* », lance-t-il en s'esclaffant, expression intraduisible désignant le purgatoire où croupissent les artistes [américains] indésirables.

Pourtant on pourrait *revenir* :

- « *du* Purgatoire des acteurs »,
- « *de la* Prison des damnés du cinéma »,
- « *des* Relégations cinématesques »,
- « *de l*'Île au Diable des intermittents (spécificités françaises) ».

Dans ce contexte, cela vous semble-t-il compréhensible et fidèle à l'image d'origine ?

---

*Suite aux suggestions de transposition... et de fil en  aiguille :*

- « *des* Zones de relégation [ du cinéma | des cinéphiles | cinématesques ] »,
- « *de l*'Oubli médiatique des acteurs »,
- « *d'un* Goulag du cinéma »,

Comment: La première traduction me semble la plus pertinente mais en ayant déjà lu l'explication, je ne suis pas certain de mon objectivité quant à la compréhensibilité hors contexte.

Comment: Les conséquences sont peut-être moins graves, mais « Movie jail » a l’aire de ressembler un peu l’équivalent en cinéma l’idée de « [relegation zone](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/relegation_zone) » en sport, qui est l’étape juste avant  [la relégation](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/rel%C3%A9gation) définitive, donc je voterais pour votre 3eme (peut-être avec « zone de » ajuté).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Si tu cherches une expression existante, on emploie souvent *"**traversée du désert**"* pour parler d'une période de faible apparition médiatique.

> [**traversée du désert**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/travers%C3%A9e_du_d%C3%A9sert) `\tʁa.vɛʁ.se dy de.zɛʁ\` *masculin*
>
> Épisode de la vie d’une personne, souvent un personnage connu, durant lequel il connaît des difficultés qui peuvent lui donner un sentiment d’abandon (médiatique, par ses amis, etc.).
>
> > *Après sa traversée du désert, elle redevient Première ministre en 2007 grâce au succès de son parti aux législatives. Cette fois, Timochenko opte pour le pragmatisme dans ses relations avec Moscou.*

---

Un [commentaire](http://www.chartsinfrance.net/Pascal-Obispo/news-82524.html#com707818) sur un site, sur Pascal Obispo, présentant bien mon point de vue :

> Son temps est révolu, sa musique est dépassée et ses 2 échecs consécutifs prouvent qu'il est dans une traversée du désert et qu'il peine à retrouver son public.

---

Comment: C'est effectivement une traduction qui correspond parfaitement aux expressions médiatiques françaises, en plus elle est multi-contextes.

Comment: C'est la meilleure traduction, car elle est répandue, on la trouve régulièrement dans la presse.

Answer (score 5):

"Les oubliettes du septième art" traduit bien la notion de "jail" et englobe tous ceux qui travaillent dans ce domaine.

Comment: C'est une jolie expression, mais je ne l'ai jamais entendue. L'as-tu créée?

Comment: *Au rayon vamps, j'ai découvert Tilda Thamar, «la bombe argentine», dans L'Aventurière des Champs-Élysées, de Roger Blanc, parfait exemple de ces films du samedi soir rapidement tombés dans **les oubliettes du septième Art**.* Le temps et rien d'autre, François Fabian, 2006

Comment: j'ai pensé à la même chose. Mais j'ai l'impression que les acteurs en question ne sont pas nécessairement oubliés, mais juste indésirable. Dans ce sens, traversée du désert est peut être mieux.

Answer (score 2):

Les suggestions de transpositions ont été ajoutées dans la question, mais, en plus de la réponse de Yohan, je pourrais employer :

> On m'a sorti des oubliettes.

Answer (score 1):

Pour la traduction de « movie », « … du cinéma » ou « … cinématique » captent bien ce sens de « movie ».
Je trouve que « des acteurs » est trop limitant car il y aussi des écrivains, metteurs en scènes, et « producers » en jeu, donc peut-être « des artistes du cinéma (ou artistes cinématiques) serait mieux que « acteurs » tout seule. (J’ajuterait «du cinéma/artistes cinématiques » âpres « des intermittents » aussi, et finalement je trouve très bien cet « intermittents du cinéma/artistes cinématiques).

Pour la traduction de « jail », comme vous remarquiez, on peut en revenir et donc, comme Chop dans un commentaire, je trouve tres bien « Purgatoire » et aussi « zone de relégation ».  Mais « relégation » seule me semble trop finale et me fait penser un peu trop aux années de McCarthy quand les artistes du cinéma étaient bannis et mis sur  les « listes noirs » pour « unamerican activities ».

Même « prison » me semble un peu trop dur et trop permanant.  Peut-être la différence entre « prison » et « jail » en anglais n’existe pas/est moins en français, mais un « jail » est pour punir les gens locaux pour moins d’un an et même pour seulement quelques heures en attendant qu’ils se remettent de leur ivresse. Un « prison », par contre, est pour les crimes plus graves et les sentences plus longues, parfois a la vie et je crois que le « jail » en « movie jail » serait mieux capté par un mot moins sinistre que « prison » (comme ‘taule’, centre de rétention ou même cellule capitonnée, peut-être ?) .

En fin compte je trouve mieux en mieux « L’ile au diable » et même « l’oubli médiatique ». Ils me font penser aux goulags et je crois que « [revenir] d’un goulag du cinéma » serait pas mal comme traduction.

Comment: Vos précisions sur le mot *jail* sont intéressantes et bien qu'il soit à l'opposé du mot *goulag* (motif, durée...) j'ai ajouté cette proposition dans le complément de la question.